# Acumatica SOAP Contract API-BusinessAccountPaymentInstructionDetail for Vendor Add

Tags: api, soap, acumatica, vendor, contract

I have a C# application that is used to upload Vendors to Acumatica. As Part of this, I want to be able to load the EFT payment information to the Payment Instructions on the Payment Setting page .It looks like I am supposed to use the BusinessAccountPaymentInstructionDetail in the API, and I have tried various ways but can't figure it out. Has anyone done this and is willing to share a sample of the code?

I am able to create the vendor fine, and then go back and update fields populated from Vendor Class. The Payment Methods and Payment Instructions are setup in Acumatica, and I am trying to update the values for each vendor when created.

This is the section of code where I am updating vendor after creation. It works fine for Checks, adding the Fedwire is where I have issues.

```
//Create a Vendor record with the specified values
Vendor newVendor = (Vendor)client.Put(VendorToBeCreated);
Debug.WriteLine("*********** Vendor was created.");

//Update values on added vendor that defaulted from Vendor Class
//Cash Account
//Payment Method
//Payment Instructions for FEDWIRE
if (PaymentMethod == "CHECK")
{                                    
newVendor.PaymentMethod.Value = PaymentMethod;
Debug.WriteLine("***********Cash Account and Payment Method Added*********");
}
else
{
if (PaymentMethod == "FEDWIRE")
{
Debug.WriteLine("***********FEDWIRE*********");                                        

//This is where I am having issues trying to figure out what to pass in

newVendor.PaymentInstructions = new BusinessAccountPaymentInstructionDetail[]
{
new BusinessAccountPaymentInstructionDetail()
{
PaymentMethod = new StringValue { Value = PaymentMethod},
Description =  new StringValue { Value = "Bank Name:"},
Value =  new StringValue { Value = "123456"},
},
new BusinessAccountPaymentInstructionDetail()
{
PaymentMethod = new StringValue { Value = PaymentMethod },
Description =  new StringValue { Value = "Bank Routing Number (ABA):" },
Value =  new StringValue { Value = "267077627" },
},                                     
new BusinessAccountPaymentInstructionDetail()
{
PaymentMethod = new StringValue { Value = PaymentMethod },
Description =  new StringValue { Value = "Beneficiary Account No:" },
Value =  new StringValue { Value = "987654321" },
},
new BusinessAccountPaymentInstructionDetail()
{
PaymentMethod = new StringValue { Value = PaymentMethod},
Description =  new StringValue { Value = "Beneficiary Name:" },
Value =  new StringValue { Value = "Jim" },
},
};
}
}
newVendor.CashAccount.Value = CashAccount;
client.Put(newVendor);
}
//End add Vendor
```

Thank you,

Jim

Comment: You need to provide a minimal code to reproduce the problem. See more details on how to post a question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong way to identify the lines

```
new BusinessAccountPaymentInstructionDetail
        {
            PaymentInstructionsID = new StringValue { Value = <line ID which is visible on Payment Method> },
            Value = new StringValue { Value = <your value> }
        }
```

Also should work with a single request

Comment: Thank you, I actually figured that out yesterday!! I was just coming back to update this post as well.

Comment: Never thought I would find the answer to this vendor-specific problem on SO, but here we are. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
newVendor.PaymentInstructions = new BusinessAccountPaymentInstructionDetail[]
{
//Beneficiary Account No
new BusinessAccountPaymentInstructionDetail()
{                                               
 PaymentInstructionsID =new StringValue { Value = "1" },                                                  
 Value =  new StringValue { Value = eftankacct },
},
//Beneficiary Name
new BusinessAccountPaymentInstructionDetail()
{
PaymentInstructionsID =new StringValue { Value = "2" },                                                     
Value =  new StringValue { Value = beneficiaryname },
},
//Bank Routing Number (ABA)
 new BusinessAccountPaymentInstructionDetail()
{
PaymentInstructionsID =new StringValue { Value = "3" },                                                  
Value =  new StringValue { Value = eftransitroutingno },
},
//Bank Name
new BusinessAccountPaymentInstructionDetail()
{
 PaymentInstructionsID =new StringValue { Value = "4" },                                               
 Value =  new StringValue { Value = bankname },
 },
};
```